# Schedule conflicts approximating program

Tags: c#, datetime

This small application is used to approximate conflicts in a schedule. Using a minimal time span of 30 minutes in my example, the application should be able to figure if there's a conflict in +/- 30 minutes range. To compute my approximation, I based my code on [this SO's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346689/design-data-structure-for-merging-meeting-schedules). The idea is to use bitwise manipulation and, splitting your schedule in parts (30 minutes in my case), attribute one bit to each 30 minutes slot in a day.

Example :

> 1:00 to 3:00 (AM) = 001111
>
> The first zeros represent the hour from 0:00 to 1:00, then the four other bits represent from 1:00 to 3:00.
>
> 1:30 to 4:00 (AM) = 00011111
>
> The three first zeros are from 0:00 to 1:30, then the 5 setted bits are for the timespan of 1:30 to 4:00.

I'm using a `long` to keep these values, which means that :

\$24hours/day*60minutes/hours= 1440 minutes/day\$

and :

\$1440minutes/30minutes/bit=48bits\$

The last 16 bits of the `long` are useless (at least, for the moment).

In order to respect my 30 minute `TimeSpan`, I round my `DateTime` to respect the said `TimeSpan` using these methods :

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Rounds down a date according to the timespan
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dateTime">DateTime to round</param>
    /// <param name="roundValue">Timespan unit used to round</param>
    /// <returns>Rounded unit</returns>
    /// <example>
    /// 2015/01/01 13:15 with TimeSpan.FromMinute(30) will round to 13:00
    /// </example>
    public static DateTime RoundDown(this DateTime dateTime, TimeSpan roundValue)
    {
        var delta = dateTime.Ticks % roundValue.Ticks;
        return new DateTime(dateTime.Ticks - delta, dateTime.Kind);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rounds up a date according to the timespan
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dateTime">DateTime to round</param>
    /// <param name="roundValue">Timespan unit used to round</param>
    /// <returns>Rounded unit</returns>
    /// <example>
    /// 2015/01/01 13:15 with TimeSpan.FromMinute(30) will round to 13:30
    /// </example>
    public static DateTime RoundUp(this DateTime dateTime, TimeSpan roundValue)
    {
        var delta = (roundValue.Ticks - (dateTime.Ticks % roundValue.Ticks)) % roundValue.Ticks;
        return new DateTime(dateTime.Ticks + delta, dateTime.Kind);
    }
}
```

I'll explain the flow of the program rapidly : We create a `Schedule`, add `ScheduleUnit`s in it, the call `ComputeApproximatedScheduleConflicts()` to get an approximation (+/- 30 minutes) of the conflicts using a `&` operator, then we create a `ScheduleConflit` per instance of conflict to print the to the console afterwards.

The conflict approximation might need some explaining :

> Say I have a `ScheduleUnit` (call it Unit1) from 1:00 to 3:00 (AM)
>
> And another `Schedule Unit` (call it Unit2) from 2:30 to 4:30 (AM)
>
> The bit representation of those units are respectively
>
> Unit1 : 001111
>
> Unit2 : 000001111
>
> The bitwise `&` comparison would result of :
>
> 001111 & 000001111 = 000001000
>
> Meaning we have a conflict between 2:30 and 3:00

```
/// <summary>
/// A schedule unit in time, must start and end on the same day
/// </summary>
public struct ScheduleUnit
{
    public Guid Id { get; }
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; }
    public DateTime Start { get; }
    public DateTime End { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds an instance of the ScheduleUnit class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">Starting time of the unit</param>
    /// <param name="end">Ending time of the unit</param>
    /// <remarks>Both start and end mus be on the same day.</remarks>
    public ScheduleUnit(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        if(start.DayOfWeek != end.DayOfWeek)
            throw new NotSupportedException("No support for schedule conflict unit on separated days.");

        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Start = start;
        End = end;
        DayOfWeek = start.DayOfWeek;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// A schedule's conflict
/// </summary>
public class ScheduleConflict
{
    public IEnumerable<ScheduleUnit> UnitsInConflict { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds an instance of the ScheduleConflict class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="unitsInConflicts">Units in conflict</param>
    public ScheduleConflict(params ScheduleUnit[] unitsInConflicts)
    {
        UnitsInConflict = new List<ScheduleUnit>(unitsInConflicts);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Conflict in {String.Join(",",UnitsInConflict.Select(c => c.Id))}{Environment.NewLine}Between { UnitsInConflict.Min(c => c.Start)} and { UnitsInConflict.Min(c => c.End)}";
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// A time schedule that manages conflicts
/// </summary>
public class Schedule
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _minimalUnitTimeSpan;
    public ICollection<ScheduleUnit> ScheduleUnits { get; } 

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds an instance of the Schedule class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="minimalUnitTimeSpan">Minimal timespan that an unit can occupy</param>
    public Schedule(TimeSpan minimalUnitTimeSpan)
    {
        _minimalUnitTimeSpan = minimalUnitTimeSpan;
        ScheduleUnits = new List<ScheduleUnit>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Computes an approximation of conflicts in the schedule based on the minimal unit's time span
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>List of conflicts</returns>
    public IEnumerable<ScheduleConflict> ComputeApproximatedScheduleConflicts()
    {
        List<ScheduleConflict> conflicts = new List<ScheduleConflict>();

        foreach (var dayOfWeek in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
        {
            conflicts.AddRange(ComputeApproximatedScheduleConflictsForADay((DayOfWeek)dayOfWeek));
        }

        return conflicts;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Computes an approximation of conflicts for one day in the schedule based on the minimal unit's time span
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dayOfWeek">Day of the week to compute</param>
    /// <returns>List of conflicts</returns>
    public IEnumerable<ScheduleConflict> ComputeApproximatedScheduleConflictsForADay(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        var dailyUnits = (from unit in ScheduleUnits
            where unit.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek
            select new
            {
                ConflictBits = ApproximateConflictBits(unit, _minimalUnitTimeSpan),
                Unit = unit
            }).ToList();

        var copyDailyUnits = dailyUnits.ToList();

        foreach (var dailyUnit in dailyUnits)
        {
            foreach (var dailyUnitCompared in copyDailyUnits)
            {
                //The "AND" operator will find conflicting times.
                long conflicts = dailyUnit.ConflictBits & dailyUnitCompared.ConflictBits;

                if (conflicts == 0 || dailyUnitCompared == dailyUnit) continue;

                yield return new ScheduleConflict(dailyUnit.Unit,dailyUnitCompared.Unit);
            }

            copyDailyUnits.Remove(dailyUnit);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Computes an approximation of the conflicts in the schedule using bit shifting.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="scheduleUnit">Unit to compute</param>
    /// <param name="minimalUnitTimeSpan">Minimal time span a unit can occupy</param>
    /// <returns>Int64 where setted bits represent a time slot in conflict according to minimal unit timespan</returns>
    /// <example>
    /// Where MinimalUnitTimeSpan = 30
    /// And unit between 1:00 and 3:00
    /// returns : 001111
    /// If units between 1:30 and 4:00
    /// returns : 00011111
    /// </example>
    private static long ApproximateConflictBits(ScheduleUnit scheduleUnit, TimeSpan minimalUnitTimeSpan)
    {
        int startBlocks = (int)(scheduleUnit.Start.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes) / minimalUnitTimeSpan.Minutes;
        int endBlocks = ((int)(scheduleUnit.End.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes) / minimalUnitTimeSpan.Minutes) - 1;
        long timeBits = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < startBlocks; i++)
            timeBits <<= 1;

        long bitPointer = timeBits;
        for (int i = startBlocks; i < endBlocks; i++)
            timeBits |= (bitPointer <<= 1);

        return timeBits;
    }
}

class TimeConflictsFinder
{
    static void Main(string[] c)
    {
        TimeSpan scheduleSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01, 1, 0, 0);
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01, 1, 30, 0);
        var scheduleUnit1 = new ScheduleUnit(dt1,dt1.AddHours(2));
        var scheduleUnit2 = new ScheduleUnit(dt2,dt2.AddHours(2).AddMinutes(30));

        Schedule schedule = new Schedule(scheduleSpan);
        schedule.ScheduleUnits.Add(scheduleUnit1);
        schedule.ScheduleUnits.Add(scheduleUnit2);

        var conflicts = schedule.ComputeApproximatedScheduleConflicts();

        foreach (var scheduleConflict in conflicts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(scheduleConflict);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using an approximation? Why not simply represent events as a pair of `DateTime`s and then list all overlapping ones?

Comment: I had performance problems before with this approach with large schedules. Also, I'd say it's an exercise with bitwise operators!

Comment: If you choose an appropriate algorithm, the exact solution should be computable in O(n*log(n)) time, i.e. comparable to the cost of sorting the events by their starting time.

Comment: I should try that out. Actually, if I'm not wrong, my solution works in O(n*log(n)) at the moment, but I should try implementing it with the `DateTime`'s to see the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have to run off to a long meeting, but this doesn't look right:

```
/// <summary>
/// Builds an instance of the ScheduleUnit class
/// </summary>
/// <param name="start">Starting time of the unit</param>
/// <param name="end">Ending time of the unit</param>
/// <remarks>Both start and end mus be on the same day.</remarks>
public ScheduleUnit(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    if(start.DayOfWeek != end.DayOfWeek)
        throw new NotSupportedException("No support for schedule conflict unit on separated days.");

    Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    Start = start;
    End = end;
    DayOfWeek = start.DayOfWeek;
}
```

The comment clearly says the `start` and `end` must be the same day and merely checking `DayOfWeek` does not help much.  It could be today (Thursday) and Thursday a week ago.  I think you would need to check 2 things:

1) `start` and `end` have the same `.Kind`, and

2) `start` and `end` have the same `.Date`.